# TypeScript setter not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following class

```
export class VibrationElement {

    private _amplitude: number;

    get amplitude(): number {
        return this._amplitude;
    }

    set amplitude(amplitude: number) {
        console.log("test");
        if (this.validate(amplitude)) {
            this._amplitude = amplitude;
        }
    }

}
```

When I define an instance of that class in a component:

```
export class VibrationPatternEditingComponent {
    
    ...

    amplitudeChange(vibration: VibrationElement, newValue: any) {
        vibration.amplitude = parseInt(newValue);
    }

}
```

So the problem here is that the setter of VibrationElement is not called (no "test" in console) but the value changes anyway. But I need to verify some constraints on the amplitude so the setter is necessary.

I also tried it with
`Object.assign(vibration, {amplitude: parseInt(newValue)});` but that also did not trigger the setter.

When I use `[(ngModel)]="vibration.amplitude"` inside an input form then the setter gets triggered but the problem here is that the input then is a string. And then I can't convert it in the setter because the setter of course gets a number but somehow it is a string when I console log `typeof amplitude` inside the setter. I really don't get it. Does somebody has an answer here?

Comment: That doesn't work. I have instances of VibrationElements. I need to change it on an object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can convert/cast `string` to `number` like so:

```
export class VibrationElement {
    
    private _amplitude: number;

    get amplitude(): number {
        return this._amplitude;
    }

    set amplitude(_amplitude) {
        const amplitude = Number(_amplitude);
        console.log("test");
        if (this.validate(amplitude)) {
            this._amplitude = amplitude;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just put a temp value in my setter. Works!